# Cannot run a process via ProcessBuilder.start() because of command not found

Tags: java, groovy, process, runtime

I am trying to run a `mvn ...` command via Groovy.

This is what I wrote:

```
def mvnPath = System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME") + "/bin/mvn"
def pomPath = new File("./pom.xml").getAbsolutePath()
Process mavenPrimaryPackagingProcess = new ProcessBuilder(
        "${mvnPath} primary-package -Pfull-release -f ${pomPath}"
    )
    .directory(new File("."))
    .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
    .start()
```

However, when I run the above, I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "c:\Maven\maven-3.8.4/bin/mvn primary-package -Pfull-release -f D:\projectRoot.\pom.xml" (in dir
> ectory "."): CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable

(The sentence "Le fichier spécifié est introuvable" is French for "The system cannot find the file specified").

As you can see from the exception message, both the `mvn` executable and the `pom.xml` are fully qualified, so I really don't understand which is the file that cannot be found.

Any idea?
The code snippet is ran via `java -jar ...` invocation on command line, with the terminal set on `D:\projectRoot` (the same folder that is printed when I do `new File(".")`).

Comment: you should split `"${mvnPath} primary-package -Pfull-release -f ${pomPath}"` to multiple strings - put each parameter into a separate string `"${mvnPath}", "primary-package",  "-Pfull-release",  "-f",  "${pomPath}"`

Comment: @daggett is correct, if you look at the Javadoc for `ProcessBuilder` you'll see that the command and arguments must be in separate strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've omitted the correct filename extension for MVN command on Windows ".CMD" and need to append so the pathname resolves properly - use `System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME") +"/bin/mvn.cmd"`.

Java is not like CMD / Powershell which checks `PATHEXT` suffixes if the provided pathname does not exist.

As per in the comment by @daggett, you also need to split the arguments to use `ProcessBuilder(String... command)`, it does not work same way as the error-prone argument splitting call `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(String)`.

If you split up the arguments but don't specify the correct filename extension for MVN command you should see a different error:

```
new ProcessBuilder(System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME") + "/bin/mvn", "your", "other", "arguments ...").start()
=> Exception java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\whatever\apache-maven-3.9.1/bin/mvn": 
   CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed a mix of not splitting the arguments and not adding the ".cmd" at the end (that I will have to change when running under Unix but that's another thing)